# Text missing from main titlebar & menus in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, fonts

I'm using a recently-installed 20.04. I've been running into problems with text disappearing from the main Gnome titlebar and menus on return from suspend:

gnome with text missing
[image]

If I go into gnome-tweaks and select a different "Interface Text" font, the text will sometimes reappear (but only for some fonts; others remain invisible, and changing the size of the font doesn't seem to make the text reappear).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried the usual `sudo fc-cache -r` routine?  Does logging out and back in make a difference (as opposed to reboot)?  (I use Kubuntu, and have noticed issues with fonts in GTK apps... but haven't yet tracked down a cause or solution.)

Comment: I hadn't tried `sudo fc-cache -r` but that does seem to work. It reloads the missing font correctly and the missing text reappears.

Comment: I guess that's a workaround until you can find and fix the underlying cause.

Answer (score 4):

I use Kubuntu, and have noticed issues with fonts in GTK apps, but haven't yet tracked down a cause or solution.  Until you are able to find and address the underlying cause, you can try the following as a workaround:

- Regenerate the font cache with `sudo fc-cache -r`, `sudo fc-cache -f`, or `sudo fc-cache`.
- Log out and back in.  It's an annoyance, but should be quicker than a reboot.
- I haven't seen the same font issues in 22.04.  Consider upgrading.

Comment: I tried several things, but this solution finally worked for me (even without the log out/log in).

Answer (score 3):

Fix for me was to restart GNOME. Ubuntu 21.

> While logged in to your GNOME desktop press ALT + F2 key combination. Into the Enter a Command box type **r** and press Enter.

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-restart-gui-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa

Comment: There is no such version of Ubuntu as 21

Comment: This works if you are log in using X11, but not Wayland.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just sharing my experience and how I fixed it. Not sure if your problem is the same or not.

Please check your log file:

```
journalctl SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=gnome-shell -n 300
```

You might find some error log similar to this:

```
gnome-shell[4918]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
```

Then add the below environment variables in your `/etc/environment`:

```
FONTCONFIG_FILE=fonts.conf
FONTCONFIG_PATH=/etc/fonts
```