# Text missing from main titlebar & menus in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: xorg, fonts

The [old issue](https://How%20do%20I%20fix%20fonts%20not%20rendering%20and%20missing%20letters?) we had in 18.04 and [20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281784/text-missing-from-main-titlebar-menus-in-ubuntu-20-04) seems to be back:

Text in UI Menus and titlebar goes missing, again.

The `sudo fc-cache -r` thing doesn't seem to do the job this time, though.

Question: how can we **permanently** fix this, so it doesn't get broken by the next set of updates?

Comment: Did you try the other solutions in that posts?

Comment: I tried everything I linked to before posting. Haven't tried again since.

Answer (score 2):

22.04.2 LTS under Wayland.

I have been suffering for some time with the same issue. Occasionally I lose all text from widgets, indicators, menus, - everything.

Do not know what the cause is yet BUT as a workaround, right click the desktop select Accessibility and switch Large Text on and off.

Works for me.

HTH

Comment: A temp fix not a solution.

Comment: Did I not use the word "workaround"? I could have sworn I did.