# Mainmenu crashes / loses fonts after a while

Tags: xorg, 22.04

Running 22.04.1 LTS.

My main menu "loses" its fonts/glyphs(?) after some time. Without any recognizable trigger, the clock, calendar, app finder and main menu don't show (most) text anymore:

[image: Main menu]

The same goes for the notification window, weirdly, some characters remain here:

[image: Notification window]

The only workaround I could find is logging out and back in or rebooting the whole machine which is unfeasible.

I realize this won't be an easy fix, but I would already appreciate pointers to relevant log or config files, I don't even know where to start with this one.

**Edit:** `inxi -G`:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: Cheng Uei Precision Industry (Foxlink) HP HD Camera type: USB
    driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 resolution: 1: 1920x1080~60Hz
    2: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.5
```

**Edit 2**
It happened again, here is the tail of `/var/log/syslog` at the time:

```
Jan 12 10:30:52 rtkit-daemon[1928]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 12 10:30:52 rtkit-daemon[1928]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 12 10:33:06 gnome-shell[9630]: y Wnck::Screen=HASH(0x5629c2906490)
Jan 12 10:33:06 gnome-shell[9630]: fct_update_tray_menu was called by Wnck::Screen=HASH(0x5629c2906490)
Jan 12 10:33:06 gnome-shell[9630]: message repeated 13 times: [ fct_update_tray_menu was called by Wnck::Screen=HASH(0x5629c2906490)]
Jan 12 10:33:44 systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs. 
Jan 12 10:33:44 anacron[102424]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2023-01-12
Jan 12 10:33:44 systemd[1]: anacron.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 12 10:33:44 anacron[102424]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Jan 12 10:33:53 rtkit-daemon[1928]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 12 10:33:53 rtkit-daemon[1928]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 12 10:34:25 gnome-shell[9630]: fct_upd
Jan 12 10:34:25 gnome-shell[5567]: Window manager warning: WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x3c14a41 for 0x3c14a4f window override-redirect is an override-redirect window and this is not correct according to the standard, so we'll fallback to the first non-override-redirect window 0x3c14457.
Jan 12 10:35:19 gnome-shell[5567]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x555bfb8b8680] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 12 10:35:19 gnome-shell[5567]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x555bfe103ee0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 12 10:35:19 gnome-shell[5567]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x555bfb9b5140] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 12 10:35:54 rtkit-daemon[1928]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 12 10:35:54 rtkit-daemon[1928]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 12 10:35:54 gnome-shell[9630]: ate_tray_menu was called by Wnck::Screen=HASH(0x5629c2906490)
Jan 12 10:35:54 gnome-shell[9630]: fct_update_tray_menu was called by Wnck::Screen=HASH(0x5629c2906490)
Jan 12 10:35:54 gnome-shell[9630]: message repeated 12 times: [ fct_update_tray_menu was called by Wnck::Screen=HASH(0x5629c2906490)]
Jan 12 10:36:53 rtkit-daemon[1928]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
```

**Edit 3** Possible Workaround

I found this [comment on gnome bugtracker](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/2389#note_1133433) and disabled the font hinting via `gnome-tweaks`. As it is discussed in the other thread and might be relevant: I have no gnome extensions enabled (or even installed).

**Edit 4** Actual Workaround / Mitigation

The best way I found to get the fonts back without rebooting is resetting the GUI by pressing `[Alt]+[F2]`, typing `r` into the command box and pressing `[Enter]`. This brings all the fonts back.

**Edit 5** More syslog info from a recent crash:

```
Jan 18 20:16:04 nb01 gnome-shell[5692]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x55e3f2a0c680] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 18 20:16:04 nb01 gnome-shell[5692]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x55e3f779db10] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 18 20:16:04 nb01 gnome-shell[5692]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x55e3f3fdadd0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 18 20:16:04 nb01 gnome-shell[5692]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x55e3f2a0c680] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 18 20:16:04 nb01 gnome-shell[5692]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x55e3f779db10] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 18 20:16:04 nb01 gnome-shell[5692]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x55e3f3fdadd0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 18 20:16:06 nb01 gnome-shell[5692]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x55e3f2a0c680] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 18 20:16:06 nb01 gnome-shell[5692]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x55e3f779d330] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 18 20:16:06 nb01 gnome-shell[5692]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x55e3f3fdb4d0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 18 20:16:06 nb01 gnome-shell[5692]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x55e3f2a0c680] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 18 20:16:06 nb01 gnome-shell[5692]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x55e3f779d330] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 18 20:16:06 nb01 gnome-shell[5692]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x55e3f3fdb4d0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 18 20:16:06 nb01 gnome-shell[5692]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x55e3f2a0c680] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 18 20:16:06 nb01 gnome-shell[5692]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x55e3f779d330] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 18 20:16:06 nb01 gnome-shell[5692]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x55e3f3fdb4d0] is on because it needs an allocation
```

.

Comment: Can you find any related errors in `/var/log/syslog` that could help solver this issue? If this happen regularly, try checking the log file as soon as it happens and see if anything shows up there.

Comment: I will check the log when it next happens, thank you!

Comment: Probably related thread, provided by @tekcins :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281784/text-missing-from-main-titlebar-menus-in-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Could you add the output of `inxi -G` to your question? Might be a GPU driver problem

Comment: @kanehekili find the command output above

Comment: Pressing `Alt`+`F2`, and typing `r` is called: _restarting gnome-shell_ :) (And can also be triggered through e.g. switching between themes back and forth. (Though your shortcut is superior.))

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the intel driver works out of box. However, the "modesetting" driver might not be as good as the intel driver.

The following instructions work **only** with an XSession - not with Wayland! [See how to change](https://askubuntu.com/a/1380838/906933)

My suggestion is to create the following file:
`/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

Add

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Intel Graphics"
  Driver "intel"
  #Option      "DRI"  "iris"
  #Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

You'll need to reboot after a change, so the drivers are updated.

More changes: (Try one after the other)

For Intel GPUs starting from Gen8 (Broadwell), the Iris Mesa driver is needed:

```
Option      "DRI"  "iris"
```

If you experience issues with default SNA (e.g. pixelated graphics, corrupt text, etc.), try using UXA instead

```
Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
```

Sorry, but this is trial & error. the `#` is a comment - so it will not be read. To activate the line just remove that sign.

In case of problems during startup, you can always remove or rename that file and reboot.

**Font rendering**

In some cases the fonts you are using can't be handled by the intel drivers [(not Linux specific)](https://community.intel.com/t5/Graphics/Font-Rendering-Problem-Letters-and-some-Icons-missing-Windows-10/td-p/1283458). You might try to change your fonts and/or your theme.

An example of a working font configuration can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593978/418943)

**Update**

Considering the new logs it seems this [Bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/4281) is responsible for the spam.

[This](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues/7743) describes the problem more clearly and is a driver problem in conjunction with mesa.Fix in `mesa 22.2.0-2`

Comment: I am using X, not Wayland, so I'm good to go on your answer. The font-hintig tweak did not work. I have created the file, so far without enabling either "Option", and restarted X. I will keep you posted

Comment: It happened again 5 minutes ago. Doesn't seem to work yet. I have now enabled the "DRI" Option.

Comment: Not quite sure, but the drivers might need a reboot instead of a log out.. The "uxa" option would be my favorite.

Comment: I think so too. Logigng out and in probably won't reload the driver. I rebooted both times I changed the config file. No issue so far using the "iris" option.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll update my answer accordingly. So I narrows the problem down to the driver, which was one of your objectives.

Comment: Thank you for your patient handholding. I'll wait a final few hours to see if the problem re-occurs

Comment: ok, we celebrated too soon. It happened again. I **disabled** the "iris" option and **enabled** the "uxa" option and rebooted. Now it's waiting a few hours again...

Comment: Could you see an entry in `dmesg` around the time the fonts got missing again? I'm still convinced it is the driver. Should be some kind of stacktrace or a "flood" warning. The latter might be a power preserving problem

Comment: Yes, this time there was possibly relevant output in `/var/log/syslog`: I've added it as edit 5 to my question

Comment: Updated my answer - not clear if that leads to the broken fonts, though