Most characters disappearing in GNOME after suspend

Legion 5 17ARH05H laptop with AMD Ryzen 7 4800H and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (issue existed with 23.10, too)
NVIDIA drivers 550 (issue exists with 535, too)

Everything works perfectly fine - until the system resumes from suspend, some examples:

Login screen


App searching


Some random notification (note also the clock is missing)



I am currently running Ubuntu 24.04 but had the same issue with Ubuntu 23.10 before and hoped it'd go away with the next LTS release. I was using 24.04 with NVIDIA driver 535 but had to upgrade to 550 because of another bug affecting me. Sadly, this made no difference to this issue. All packages are up-to-date.
Note: Within applications (e.g., Firefox, Thunderbird, gnome-terminal) everything is fine - this seems to affect only gnome itself.
The bug can reliably be triggered with every suspend/resume. This computer was able to suspend/resume before using Ubuntu 20.04. Restarting gdm resolves the issue but is obviously not a good solutions as all windows are forcefully killed.
Any ideas what I can do to resolve/debug this issue?
edit 1: Replying to the comments so far:

Alt+F2 and then r + Enter shows this screen but nothing else happens:

When using the integrated graphics, screen dimming doesn't work (always at 100%)
Tags modified
kill -3 $(pidof gnome-shell) forcefully closes applications just as restarting gdm does
It seems possible by "restoring" at least the text by changing the font in gnome-tweaks after resume, it's still not great...:

Workaround: Switching to the open source driver (uninstalling cuda) works - the system is now also to suspend/resume without artifacts


Don't know how to resolve but to make display go back to normal, you can do Alt+F2 then press r and enter. I will restart your display.

I think it's the nvidia driver (based on earlier bug reports posted on this site, that looked somewhat similar). If you would have hybrid graphics hardware (not only dedicated card, but also integrated graphics on the processor), you could lean towards the integrated one, as a workaround. Otherwise it's about juggling with proprietary vs open source nvidia drivers.

I would update the tags on your question to include nvidia, graphics, and drivers.

kill -3 $(pidof gnome-shell)

Does this issue persist with the new beta 555 driver?  Also are you up to date on BIOS? Looks like latest is FSCN28WW but of course will require windows to install. Not sure if that has anything to do with it but maybe there are suspend-related issues?  Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281784/text-missing-from-main-titlebar-menus-in-ubuntu-20-04  and https://askubuntu.com/questions/795278/how-to-fix-missing-characters-from-font-after-awakening-from-suspend

Well, restart is not available on Wayland (Alt+F2, r doesn't work), kill -3 $(pidof gnome-shell) just freeze the system. Is there any other way to restart the nvidia driver?
